# QML TreeView items are not updated when emitting dataChanged

Tags: c++, qt, treeview, qml, qtquickcontrols

I have a QML `TreeView` like this:

```
  TreeView
  {
    id: treeview
    model: myModel
    anchors.fill: parent
    alternatingRowColors: false
    headerVisible: false

    TableViewColumn
    {
      title: "Name"
      role: "name"
      delegate: Text
      {
      text: styleData.value
      }
    }
```

However, when I emit dataChanged from a custom method in C++, nothing is updated:

```
void MyModel::NameChanged()
{
  // beginResetModel(); <=== Works
  // endResetModel();

  // emit dataChanged(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex()); // Does not work

  auto topLeftIndex = createIndex(0, 0, m_root.get());
  auto bottomRightIndex = createIndex(rowCount(), columnCount(), m_root.get());
  (( emit dataChanged(topLeftIndex, bottomRightIndex);  // Does not work.
  emit dataChanged(topLeftIndex, topLeftIndex);  // Does not work.
}
```

In QML, `text` is bound to `styleData.value` and I am not setting text anywhere else. Also, dataChanged is not redefined elsewhere. So I am sure I am really emitting `QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged(...)`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

My index method:

```
QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parentIdx) const
{
  if (hasIndex(row, column, parentIdx) == false)
  {
    return QModelIndex();
  }

  auto parentItem = m_root.get();
  if (parentIdx.isValid() == true)
  {
    parentItem = static_cast<ModelItem *>(parentIdx.internalPointer());
  }

  auto childItem = parentItem->GetChild(row);
  auto childName = childItem->GetName().toStdString();
  if (childItem)
  {
    auto index = createIndex(row, column, childItem.get());
    return index;
  }
  else
  {
    return QModelIndex();
  }
}
```

My parent method:

```
QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &childIndex) const
{
  if (childIndex.isValid() == false)
  {
    return QModelIndex();
  }

  auto childItem = static_cast<ModelItem*>(childIndex.internalPointer());
  auto parentItem = childItem->GetParent();

  if (parentItem.expired() == true)
  {
    return QModelIndex();
  }

  auto pItem = parentItem.lock();
  if (pItem == nullptr)
  {
    return QModelIndex();
  }

  auto parentIndex = createIndex(pItem->GetRow(), 0, pItem.get());
  return parentIndex;
}
```

**UPDATE: if I use my model in C++ using a QTreeView, then it works.**

Comment: You need to provide valid indexes of which data changed.

Comment: @Hayt: are you sure about this? Because I read that if we pass invalid indices, then it will update the entire model.

Comment: the documentation says nothing about this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged

Comment: This question is still highly relevant and there is no answer yet!

Answer (score 1):

While `beginResetModel()` and `endResetModel()` will invalidate the whole view, `dataChanged()` only invalidates a range you give it.

If you know what value changed you can use it like

```
 emit dataChanged(createIndex(row,col),createIndex(row,col));
```

or when multiple lines/cells change the second parameter is the "last" index which changed.

Comment: I updated my question to test your suggestion. Please have a look.

Comment: What does your `parent()` function return? the documentation says these indexes need to have the same parent. You should have one `dummy` element which acts as a parent for all other indexes.

Comment: I have a dummy root. But as I am modifying some of its children, then I return an invalid QModelIndex (because their parent is the dummy root). This is the solution explained here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html

Comment: when do you return an invalid QModelIndex? Can you add your index() and your parent() function to your question? I would guess you somewhere have something wrong with your indexes.

Comment: I added the index and parent method to my question. As display and reset are working fine, I never re-read them actually and considered they were fine.

Comment: you seem to create a different parent item per row. so when you emit dataChanged across rows the rows each have a different parent. When you have one "dummy parent item" you should also just return the same index for it.

Comment: "you seem to create a different parent item per row.". Can you give me more details please? Where do you see that? I am not sure I understood actually. Thanks.

Comment: `auto parentIndex = createIndex(pItem->GetRow(), 0, pItem.get());` this creates a different parent index for each row. try `createIndex(0,0,...)` or so

Comment: Each row (with the same parent), will return the same pItem. So pItem->GetRow() is the same (GetRow() returns the row of current element in its parent).

Comment: Yes so each row has a different parent. and `dataChanged` is undefined if you pass indexes with different parent in them.

Comment: If I do emit dataChanged(topLeftIndex, topLeftIndex);, it is not working as mentioned in my question. So even with the same index, it is not working. Also, other than updating when I internally set data, everything is working correctly. Also, I checked in a specific example, and even if I do createIndex(0, 0, pItem.get()); it is not working.

Comment: I ended implemented this using a C++ QTreeView and it works fine. I have no idea why it is not working in QML though.

Comment: @Hayt, I think you should update your answer with advice about the `parent()` function.

Comment: @Korchkidu I am not sure if child items are updated when you update your parent item (i.e. root item in your case). However, have you tried updating one specific item (that is not root)? This works for me